# Splitting Date into 2 Columns (Date + Time) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert the Date key in my table which is numeric into date time key.  My current query is:

```
  SELECT 
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
  SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' 
  Order By Date DESC;
```

The Date Column shows this:
2013-06-22 13:36:44.403

I want to split this into two columns:
Date:
2013-06-22

Time (Remove Microseconds):
13:36:44

Can anyone modify my existing query to display the required output? That would be greatly appreciated.  Please Note: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want to investigate the convert() function:

```
  select convert(date, getdate()) as [Date], convert(varchar(8), convert(time, getdate())) as [Time]
```

gives

```
  Date       Time
  ---------- --------
  2013-07-16 15:05:43
```

Wrapping these around your original SQL gives the admittedly very ugly:

```
SELECT convert(date, 
      DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)))) [Date],
  convert(varchar(8), convert(time, 
      DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))))) [Time],

  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' 
  Order By Date DESC;
```

You may want to move part of this into a view, just to reduce complexity.

Comment: how would I get it to display the required output from the question?

Comment: Replace getdate() with the [Date] field in your original SQL. I'll update the answer slightly to include your original question.

Comment: And where would I add that in my query? is it possible for you to add that in my existing query and then post it as an answer so I'm able to test it right away.

Comment: Can you illustrate what the [Date] column is in your source data, so I have a value to test against? Ta.

Comment: Initially it was 20130622.133644403.  But so far I've converted it to 2013-06-22 13:36:44.403

Comment: it gave me this error when I tried your suggestion: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't completely clear from your original question that you were dealing with a date in that format. Will alter answer.

Comment: @omarK, I recommend bookmarking http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx. I use it frequently for date conversions.

Comment: Why is duplicated that code regarding the conversion from `varchar` to `date/time` (4 x `SUBSTRING` x 2) ?

Comment: It was simply to wrap the OP's code in the convert() functions I originally proposed to illustrate their use; there is room for improvement, but I'm loathe to significantly alter it now it's been accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,[Date])
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),[Date])
```

Comment: Most of the time it is the simple answer that gets it done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [STUFF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE([Date] VARCHAR(20));
INSERT  @MyTable ([Date])
VALUES  ('20130622133644403');

SELECT  y.*,
        CONVERT(DATE,y.Date_AsDateTime) AS OnlyDate,
        CONVERT(TIME(0),y.Date_AsDateTime) AS OnlyTime
FROM(
    SELECT  x.[Date] AS Date_AsVarChar, CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(x.[Date],9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),18,0,'.')) AS Date_AsDateTime
    FROM    @MyTable x
) y;
```

Results:

```
Date_AsVarChar       Date_AsDateTime         OnlyDate   OnlyTime
-------------------- ----------------------- ---------- --------
20130622133644403    2013-06-22 13:36:44.403 2013-06-22 13:36:44
```

**Solution:**

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE,y.Date_AsDateTime) AS OnlyDate,
    CONVERT(TIME(0),y.Date_AsDateTime) AS OnlyTime
FROM(
    SELECT [Object], MsgId, Parms,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(x.[Date],9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),18,0,'.')) AS Date_AsDateTime
    FROM JnlDataSection
) A
WHERE   MsgID = '325' 
-- SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' is not SARG-able
AND     Parms LIKE 'V40449%' 
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add that logic to my existing query? To only display OnlyDate and OnlyTime?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following scenario for getting the date,time,day,month,year,hours,minutes,seconds,AM/PM:

```
select 
   UpdatedOn , CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100) DateTime, CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,10) Date , 
   CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108) Time , substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),1,2) Day, 
   substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),4,3) CMonth,    
   substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,105),4,2) 
   NMonth, substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,106),8,4) Year,      
   left(right(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100),7),2) Hours_12, 
   substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),1,2) Hours_24, 
   substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),4,2) Minutes, 
   substring(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,108),7,2) Second, right(CONVERT(varchar,UpdatedOn,100),2)    
   AM_PM 
from 
   dbo.DeviceAssignSim where AssignSimId=55;
```