# In SQL Server how can I split a TransactionDateTime column into two separate columns Date and Time?

Tags: sql-server

Team,

I have a TransactionDateTime column with data and time information together like this - 2016-03-14 03:32:44.000.

I am looking for a Split Function in SQL server 2005 that would split this column into two separate columns one for "Date" and another for "Time" and the final output will look like this.---- Date (2016-03-14) and Time (03:32:44.000)

```
TransactionDateTime            Date              Time
2016-03-1403:32:44.000         2016-03-14        03:32:44.000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting Date into 2 Columns (Date + Time) in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678551/splitting-date-into-2-columns-date-time-in-sql)

Comment: No, it was not duplicate. Also, above two examples quite didn't work for me but this one.------select ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,101)as [Date],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,108)as [Time]

FROM   Qualified Table Name

Comment: What makes you say it is not a duplicate?   It doesn't have to be exact as long as the logic is the same.

Comment: Not to take personally. However, professionally speaking those answers have unnecessary lengthy explanations. I tried to work it through and gave up as I found better solution which was brief and to the point and it worked excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @dateTime datetime = getDate()
SELECT 
    @dateTime TransactionDateTime,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@dateTime,101) as [Date],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@dateTime,108) as [Time]
```

You can typecast to date/time accordingly since the output is varchar.

Comment: It worked with little modifications on my side as here under.:select ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,101)as [Date],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),ViewBTGPSStopsPerDay.StartDateTime,108)as [Time]

FROM   Qualified Table Name

Comment: I am glad to hear that, if my answer helped you to get on your way please mark it as such.

Comment: It really worked. It was brief and to the point explanation. I took code snippet and played with it and it worked. I tried other solutions but due to lengthy explanation struggled to try it out and gave up whereas yours worked.

Answer (score -1):

This should work...

> select getdate(), convert(date, getdate()), convert(varchar(10),
>   getdate(), 108)

Replace "getdate()" with your TransactionDateTime.

Noel

Comment: Nope, won't work since the `DATE` and `TIME` data types don't exist in SQL Server 2005

Comment: I has been so long since I worked with SQL Server 2005 I didn't realize that `DATE` and `TIME` data types weren't there. Sorry.

Comment: It didn't quite work.! I found the solution looking at other examples and I have posted my solution that worked. Look above.